# How to specify my grouping with a lamda function and keep other columns I need in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have grouped a dataframe. Then I want to use a lambda function throughout those groups. However, the code I am using is not returning the proper results. I'm thinking there is a problem with the grouping or perhaps the lambda function. Very specifically, I'm looking to take the grouped dataframe and only return the rows with the highest JUGCODE count. The n for how many of the highest rows to return depends of the SPOT_NUM for that group. So, every group should return a different number of rows.

I've tried changing the grouping in my original dataframe. Then I tried specifying the grouping I want in the line with the lambda function. I've also researched resetting the index. I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it. But I am still not getting the results I'm looking for.

```
#subsetting the logs
filtered_logs = log_master.loc[(log_master['BILL_TYPE'] == "Town")]
#grouping the logs by everything except the JUGCODE - because that's the count I need
town_grouped = filtered_logs.groupby(['SPOT_ID','TIME', 'R_CODE', 'SPOT_NUM', 'CONTRACT_ID', 'NAME', 'CHNN', 'ZONE', 'MONTH', 'BILL_TYPE', 'MASTER', 'DATE', ]).count()
town_grouped1 = town_grouped.reset_index()
town_grouped1.head(10)
```

That's how I grouped the dataframe that I'm going to use in my lambda function.

```
verified_spots = town_grouped1.groupby('SPOT_ID').apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest((town_grouped1['SPOT_NUM'].iloc[0]), ['JUGCODE']))
```

I'm finding that some groups are returning more rows than the SPOT_NUM for its group. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

sample data code:

```
data = [['363662402','17:24:29','1061',3,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/01/2016',30], ['363662402',   '17:31:15','1061',3,'647333','BL08253062','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC',   '10/03/2016',30], ['363662402','17:34:15','1061',3,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/02/2016',29], ['363662402','17:34:30','1061',3,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/02/2016',1], ['363662403','16:26:14','1061',3,'647333','BL08258415','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/09/2016',30], ['363662394','20:39:12','1061',4,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/02/2016',30], ['363662394','22:48:01','1061',4,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/02/2016',30], ['363662394','22:40:21','1061',4,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/01/2016',29], ['363662394','19:44:51','1061',4,'647333','BL08253061','CMDY','Savannah','201610','tampa','COMIC','10/01/2016',23]]

town_grouped1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SPOT_ID','TIME', 'R_CODE', 'SPOT_NUM', 'CONTRACT_ID', 'NAME', 'CHNN', 'ZONE', 'MONTH', 'BILL_TYPE', 'MASTER', 'DATE', 'JUGCODE'])
```

Comment: providing some sample data (better yet code to generate sample date) and expected output would make this easier to play around with and answer the question

Comment: I just edited to add in sample data. I gave what the grouping dataframe looks like. This is the data that the lambda function is applied to.

Comment: @SoSincere3 you don't refer to the correct dataframe to get the number of rows you want, replace `town_grouped1['SPOT_NUM'].iloc[0]` by `grp['SPOT_NUM'].iloc[0]` in the `nlargest`

Comment: @Ben.T This absolutely solves it! Will you please explain how grp is a dataframe? I used in in my lambda function thinking that it was referring to the previous grouping I made.

Comment: @SoSincere3 it is actually your grouped data, but the type of `grp` is dataframe. You need to get the value of SPOT_NUM for each group, so to get the good value, then use `grp` that refer to the group instead of `town_grouped1` that refer to all the data and the first value will always be the first value of this dataframe. if it makes sense